# how to repeat loop based on user selection using scanner in java

Tags: java

Hi below is my Progarm

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Usecase1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Usecase1 us = new Usecase1();
        us.withdrawl();

    }

public void withdrawl() {
    System.out.println("your Account number is....0091236452312");
    System.out.println("please enter your pin number(1234)....");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int pinno = sc.nextInt();
    if (pinno == 1234) {
        System.out
                .println("Please select type of Transaction 1.Balance Enquiry 2.Withdraw Money");
        int option = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("your choice is..." + option);
        int totalamount = 85000;
         if (option == 2) {
            System.out.println("enter amount to withdraw");
            int amount = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Remaining Balance in your account is..."
                    + (totalamount - amount));
        } 

    }
}
}
```

My requirement is to user can give his choice as 2 any number of times, for every time the below loop should be repeated please help me how to do this.

```
(option == 2) {
                System.out.println("enter amount to withdraw");
                int amount = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Remaining Balance in your account is..."
                        + (totalamount - amount));
            }
```

Comment: use a `while loop` like `while(true) { if (option == 2) { //do somthing & break when no more action needed}}`

Comment: you have one more option using `continue` when option == 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `while` loop for that and a `boolean` to flag the loop

```
boolean isValid = true;
int totalamount = 85000;
while(isValid){
  System.out.println("Please select type of Transaction 1.Balance Enquiry 2.Withdraw Money 3.Exit");
        int option = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("your choice is..." + option);
         if (option == 2) {
            System.out.println("enter amount to withdraw");
            int amount = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Remaining Balance in your account is..."
                    + (totalamount - amount));
        } else if(option == 3){
           //exit
           isValid = false;
         }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? 1.yes 2.no");

        int lastPrompt = sc.nextInt();

        if(lastPrompt == 2){
         break; or isValid = false;
         }
}
```

Comment: thanks its working, last doubt ....Before repeating we need to display a message saying do u want to continue id user says yes only loop should be repeated, please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

use a `while` loop and 
use `break` or `continue` to control over loop based on you condition.
eg-

```
while(true){   
     if (option == 2) {
                    System.out.println("enter amount to withdraw");
                    int amount = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Remaining Balance in your account is..."
                            + (totalamount - amount));
                }
     else{
            break;//break the loop
            //or you may continue the loop 
         } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the if(option == 2) with a while loop:

```
    while (option == 2) {
        System.out.println("enter amount to withdraw");
        int amount = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Remaining Balance in your account is..." + (totalamount - amount));

        //Stay in the loop if option is 2 again     
        option = sc.nextInt();
    }
```

But if you want to consider more options, then use a flag like in the answers below